# derivative of erf when argument contains two variables

Tags: derivatives, error-function

I don't understand how to take the derivative of the error function when the argument of the error function contains two variables (x and t). So,

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{erf}(\lambda) }{\partial x}$$

where

$$\lambda = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{Dt}}$$

Comment: You're taking the partial w.r.t. $x$, so you treat $t$ like a constant.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did this come up when studying an application in diffusion? That solution seems strikingly familiar

Comment: @S.D.   Yes, it is from a diffusion application that I am struggling with.

Comment: So, the derivative of the error function is:

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{erf}(x) }{\partial x}=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}$$



and if I set

$$A = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{Dt}}$$

then:

$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{erf}(Ax) }{\partial x}=\frac{2A}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-\lambda^2}$$

I'm not sure if this is right and I'm particularly not sure if the argument for the exponent is x or $\lambda$.